# is apache xmlrpc 3.1.3 compatible with Java 11?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, java-11

I'm working on an analysis to upgrade our flagship product to work with Java 11. The first stage in this process is going through our entire dependency list and figuring out which version we're using of each dependency, which version is the most recent release, what version is the earliest full release which is stated to be compatible with java 9-11 (since things that were deprecated in Java 9 won't be finally removed until Java 12) and if there are any major interoperability problems with other dependencies we use.

One of the dependencies I came across is apache-xmlrpc-2.0.1 (yeah, old version, I know), which from what I can tell has essentially not been updated in a decade, since 3.1.3, the most recent version, released in 2010. Now, I know that the XML-RPC spec hasn't updated since about 2003, but Java has, especially with regards to reflection, which from what I understand might be relevant for converting classes to XML and back so they can be sent through RPC. I've also checked some of the source, and it appears that certain parts of Apache XmlRPC that we (like secure.SecureWebServer.java) use the com.sun.net.ssl packages, which seem to have been deprecated.

So, is Apache XmlRPC 3.1.3 compatible with Java 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used apache xmlrpc 3.1.3 with Java 11 in the last couple weeks and found it worked fine. It was in a library without a great deal of other dependencies, mostly Jackson and httpclient stuff, but got the job done for me.